# How to set background color of an UIStepper instance?

Tags: iphone, ios, uistepper

When setting the background color property of an UIStepper object, I get a result as shown:

[image]

Just the corners get colored, not the expected, big background area. Is there a simple solution or does it come to iterating through the stepper's subviews?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `UIStepper` contains 3 subviews: an `UIImageView` and 2 `UIButtons`. The plus and minus signs are set via the image property of the 2 buttons. So you have to change the images of buttons.

```
UIStepper *stepper = [[UIStepper alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50)];

    for (UIView *view in stepper.subviews) {

        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {

            UIButton *button = (UIButton *)view;
            [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        }
    }

    [baseView addSubview:stepper];
```

Comment: Yep, it works. It is useful to set an image for UIControlStateDisabled as well.

Comment: By the way: A UIStepper contains 3 subviews: an UIImageView and 2 UIButtons. The plus and minus signs are set via the image property of the 2 buttons.

Comment: Any solution that involves walking the view hierarchy and expecting certain types of element to be there is a fragile solution as Apple changes the hierarchy of their basic controls frequently. This is a good example, as the basic subview of UIStepper is now a single UIStepperHorizontalVisualElement, which in turn contains numerous image views and the required buttons.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know why Apple turns it so hard to customize without images. 
What solved in my case was set the property `cornerRadius` from `UIStepper` object:

```
yourStepper.layer.cornerRadius = 5.f;
```

Comment: If anyone is like me and doesn't really want to touch the standard +/- images, then this answer is the easier, just-works solution! Who cares why it works ;-) iOS 9 at least.

Answer (score 0):

The `UIStepper` has changed significantly since this question was answered. While you can still walk the view hierarchy looking for buttons if you like, this kind of solution is prone to failing when the OS updates since Apple frequently change the view hierarchy of their custom controls.

The official way to change the appearance of `UIStepper` objects is using four functions on `UIStepper` instances: `setBackgroundImage()`, `setDividerImage()`, `setIncrementImage()` and `setDecrementImage()`. All of these accept an image and a control state, which is nice since it means you can customise the control for when it is disabled, selected and so forth. It does, however, mean you have to make a lot of annoying surplus images.

I have a nice little extension on UIImage for making suitable images from simple colours (note that I'm also using a custom Error - I won't bore you with how to make those!)

```
extension UIImage {
    static func create(size: CGSize, color: UIColor, scale: CGFloat = 1) throws -> UIImage {
        let trueSize = size * scale
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(trueSize)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        
        guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            throw AppError.cannotProcessImage
        }
        
        color.setFill()
        ctx.fill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: trueSize))
        guard let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else {
            throw AppError.cannotProcessImage
        }

        if scale == 1 { return image }
        
        guard let cgimage = image.cgImage else {
            throw AppError.cannotProcessImage
        }
        
        return UIImage(cgImage: cgimage, scale: scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
    }
}
```

Now I need to make and assign the background and divider images. Note that I'm using some custom colours from an asset catalogue so I can support Dark Mode.

```
private func updateColours() {
    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    let bgColor = UIColor(named: "Colors/BackdropC")!
    let bgSize = stepper.bounds.size
    let background = try! UIImage.create(size: bgSize, color: bgColor, scale: scale)
    stepper.setBackgroundImage(background, for: .normal)
    
    let dividerColor = UIColor(named: "Colors/TitleText")!
    let dividerSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: bgSize.height)
    let divider = try! UIImage.create(size: dividerSize, color: dividerColor)
    stepper.setDividerImage(divider, forLeftSegmentState: .normal, rightSegmentState: .normal)
}
```

I can use a little trick when setting the increment and decrement images. I simply copy the existing ones, and set them to rendering mode 'alwaysTemplate'. This will cause them to echo the control's tint colour:

```
    let incImage = stepper.incrementImage(for: .normal)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    stepper.setIncrementImage(incImage, for: .normal)
    
    let decImage = stepper.decrementImage(for: .normal)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    stepper.setDecrementImage(decImage, for: .normal)
```

Of course, all of this malarkey only sets the images for `normal` mode, and holding one of the buttons will make things change slightly, so you might want to set different images for the `highlighted` state at the least. The divider is a particular sticking point as it has FOUR possible states, depending on whether left, right, both or neither buttons are being depressed. I won't go into that here.

One final thing to note though is that I'm allowing dark mode in my app. Images created from asset-based colours won't automatically change when dark mode is turned on or off, so we have to do that manually by calling the above function from `traitCollectionDidChange`

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    self.updateColours()
}
```

So, as you can see, UIStepper is now very customisable, but to customise everything you need to change a LOT of images manually. It therefore might be slightly less painful to simply make your own version of UIStepper from a couple of buttons.